# Updating values in local dataBase error: CommandText property has not been initialized

Tags: c#, sql, sql-update, sql-server-ce, local-database

I've created some sort of application that keeps a database of employees and their payments. It works well so far. But now I'm trying to implement an "update" feature, if there is some data that changes for specific user.

So I wrote the following code for the update, but I get this error:

> CommandText property has not been initialized at line 105: "cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();"

Thanks !

```
var connString = @"Data Source=C:\Users\Andrei\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Stellwag\Stellwag\Angajati.sdf";

using (var conn = new SqlCeConnection(connString))
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();

        SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand();
        //conecteaza cmd la conn
        cmd.Connection = conn;

        //adauga parametru pt campul poza cu value image
        SqlCeParameter picture = new SqlCeParameter("@Poza", SqlDbType.Image);

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, pictureBox1.Image.RawFormat);
        byte[] a = ms.GetBuffer();
        ms.Close();

        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Poza", a);

        var query = "UPDATE info SET Nume='" + textBox5.Text + "' AND Prenume='" + textBox4.Text + "' AND Data='" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString() + "' AND Proiect='" + textBox1.Text + "' AND Schimburi='" + label10.Text + "' AND Poza=@Poza AND Acord='" + textBox2.Text + "' AND Baza='" + textBox3.Text + "'  WHERE Nume='" + label8.Text + "' AND Prenume='" + label5.Text + "'";

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("Salvat cu succes!");
        this.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must set `cmd.CommandText`

```
                //Codes
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Salvat cu succes!");
                this.Close();
```

Comment: the value sets should be separated by `,` not `AND`

Answer (score 1):

Add `cmd.CommandText = query;` above your Execution.

Comment: Thanks. Solved. Missed typed.